# How to sum time in php?

Tags: php

PHP: How to sum the result of a foreach statement?

Below is my working code.  As you will see, I'm trying to count the days in each month and then sum them.

```
//  A function to calculate days in a given month using just the date
function daysInMonths($date)
{
    $month = date("m", strtotime($date));
    $year =  date("Y", strtotime($date)); 
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); 
    return $num;
}       

// A function that places the date of an unknown number of months into an array:
function getNextMonths($date, $numberOfMonths)
{
    $timestamp_now = strtotime($date);
    $months[] = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp_now);

    for($i = 1;$i <= $numberOfMonths; $i++)
        {
            $months[] = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime($months[0].' +'.$i.' month')));
        }

// counts the days in each month:
    $j=0;
    foreach ($months as $days)
    {
        echo "$j:".daysInMonths($days)."<br>";
        ++$j;            
    }
    print_r($months);
}

getNextMonths('2011-11-1', '4');
```

Current output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2011-11-01 
    [1] => 2011-12-01 
    [2] => 2012-01-01 
    [3] => 2012-02-01 
    [4] => 2012-03-01 
)
```

After counting:
0:30
1:31
2:31
3:29
4:31

This is all correct, I'm just having trouble summing the array after I have the days of the month counted.

Comment: Your `calDaysInMonth()` function could be replaced with a simple `date('t', $date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tot = 0;
foreach ($months as $days) {
    $tot += daysInMonths(days);
}
echo $tot;
```

Comment: Wow.  That was easy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

array_sum() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

```
$t = array(
    31,
    28,
    31
);

echo array_sum($t); // 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter like you use in for while etc!!

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example